# Is there an SVG collection or a set of "stickers" for free?

Tags: svg, free

I'm looking for a set (or multiple sets) of stickers in SVG or at least good PNG (with transparent background).
By stickers I mean like what some chat application uses like a collection of a pig doing stuff (sleeping, jumping, showering, etc)

Thansk for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean Emojis, these emoji packs from artists in [DeviantArt](https://www.deviantart.com/) and other places may help:

- [iOS emoji collection by Dabolus](https://dabolus.deviantart.com/art/Complete-Emoji-Collection-555211222) (160×160 transparent PNGs)
- [iOS 9 emoji collcetion by Dabolus](https://dabolus.deviantart.com/art/iOS-9-Emojis-704898108)
- [Newly added iOS emojis by   Kiyanoush](https://sta.sh/01uf800338x2)

Comment: AFAIK the iOS emojis are copyrighted and cannot be used for anything else outside Apple ecosystem. I was refering to something similar of http://www.stickpng.com/cat/at-the-movies/cartoons/puppy-dog-pals?page=1

Comment: It depends. Are you searching for stickers of a certain cartoon or movie? or any set of a character with different expressions?